# docker build - use a containers network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-compose

I have a windows 10 host, using docker desktop 4.6.1. I have a `docker-compose.yml` which contains the two services vpn and app. What I want to achieve is, that the build process of docker already uses the vpn containers network connection.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  vpn:
    ...
  app:
    ...
    network_mode: service:vpn
```

The app container itself correctly uses the vpn container connection, as I could verify this by testing. But the build process seems to use the hosts network.
Dockers build command has a [`network`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) or [`networkmode`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ImageBuild) argument that allows to use a specific containers network. But it gives me an error:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  vpn:
    ...
  app:
    build:
      network: container:vpn
    network_mode: service:vpn
```

`docker compose up -d`

> network mode "container:vpn" not supported by buildkit. You can define
> a custom network for your builder using the network driver-opt in
> buildx create.

**How would I use buildx in my example?** I am quite confused by the documentation which talks about context and endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Split those both services into two seperate compose files

`docker-compose-vpn.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  vpn:
    ...
```

`docker-compose-app.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    image: username:app
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    network_mode: container:vpn
```

2.) Create and bring up vpn container

```
docker compose -f docker-compose-vpn.yml up -d
```

3.) Create a new vpn builder instance

```
docker buildx create --name vpn-builder --driver docker-container --driver-opt network=container:vpn --use
```

4.) Create image using your buildx vpn instance and publish it (`--load`) to docker.

```
docker buildx b -f Dockerfile-app --load --no-cache --tag username:app .
```

5.) Start the new app container

```
docker compose -f docker-compose-app.yml up -d
```